# Sampling line into list of points

Tags: qgis-3, lines-to-points

I'm trying to sample a line in a bunch of points, but when I use vector/geometry tool/extract summit I get too many points.

I'm working on Switzerland Highway, as the points are generated on every line summit I got 628 000 points for all the lines. I want these points to be separated from 100m.

I would like to set a minimum inner distance between 2 points. What are my options?

I tried to but the result is really random sometimes I get my 100m sample but in the case of very long direct line I got from 1 to 20km without any points even by reducing the simplification

I'm using QGIS 3.8

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What software are you using? How many are "too many" points?

Comment: and what kind of sampling are we doing? Just spatial locations along the linestring, or are you sampling a DTM (to get height).  If you are just sampling new points along a linestring, then would a "simplify" operation be more appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

How about using **Points along geometry** tool, under the `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`.

You can set the interval (`Distance` parameter) as you like to avoid too many points.

[image]